How to find a suitable martingale?
Background: Let $k \ge 0$. Let $X_n = k + Y_1 + \ldots + Y_n$ be a "biased" coin-tossing process, where the random variables $Y_j$, $j \in \mathbb{N}_+$ are independent and identically distributed with:
$$\mathbb{P}(Y_1 = 1) = p, \quad \mathbb{P}(Y_1 = -1) = 1 - p, \quad p \neq \frac{1}{2}.$$
Let $0 \le k \le m$, define:
$$T := \inf\{n \ge 0 : X_n = 0 \text{ or } X_n = m\}.$$
One can check that $T$ is indeed a stopping time and $T < \infty$ a.s.
In my textbook, in order to calculate $\mathbb{P}(X_T = m)$, the author claims that:
$$Z_n = \left(\frac{1 - p}{p}\right)^{X_n}$$
is a martingale.
An application of the Optional Stopping Theorem to $Z_{n\wedge T}(n\wedge T=\min \{n,T\})$ shows that:
$$\left(\frac{1 - p}{p}\right)^k = \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\frac{1 - p}{p}\right)^{X_T}\right] = \left(\frac{1 - p}{p}\right)^m \mathbb{P}(X_T = m) + \mathbb{P}(X_T = 0).$$
Now we can compute $\mathbb{P}(X_T = m)$.
Question: It is easy to check $Z_n$ is a martingale, but how can one find $Z_n$ in a more intuitive way? Is the suitable martingale $Z_n$ obtained by guessing?
